# convert xml to excel with specific xml element using java

Tags: java, xml, excel

```
<ns2:CategoryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.google.com/definitions/ps/v3" currentpage="0"         querydate="2013-09-17T02:33:08.080-04:00" resptime="69ms" resultsperpage="0" totalresults="1">
<category id="65">
   <product id="12304"/>
   <product id="462289"/>
   <product id="340287"/>
   <product id="378825"/>
   <product id="366310"/>
</category>
</ns2:CategoryResponse>
```

In the above xml context[sample.xml], I want to store the product ids from the sample.xml into Excel file using java. Please some on help on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look to this tutorial, it's little big long, but really great explanation.

[xml to excel and viceVersa](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2006/jw-1019-xmlexcel.html?page=1)